# How i say the interpreter version for wsgi apache

Tags: apache2, debian, system-administration, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

In debian recently change de default version of python from 2.5 to 2.6 but i need 2.5, how i can configure apache and/or wsgi script to say it use pythons2.5 and not python default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install mod_wsgi package binary compiled against Python 2.5, or compile mod_wsgi from source code yourself against the Python 2.5 version. See notes about --with-python option in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide#Configuring_The_Source_Code

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to recompile mod_wsgi against the appropriate version of Python.